# Motion in a straight line

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, projectile

Velocity and acceleration are directly proportional to each other but in the case of throwing a ball up , at the top velocity is zero but acceleration is there. why?

Comment: *"Velocity and acceleration are directly proportional to each other"*. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: *Velocity and acceleration are directly proportional to each other.* In 1D all vectors are proportional to each other at any instant. This is not a helpful way to think about velocity and acceleration because the “constant of proportionality” changes.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? She's new and obviously started studying physics or sth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't the acceleration at the top point of a ball’s journey zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210329/why-isnt-the-acceleration-at-the-top-point-of-a-ball-s-journey-zero)

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration is the rate of change of velocity with respect to time. When we press the brakes of a car, that rate is negative. It is the most simple example of velocity in a direction (forward in the case) and acceleration in the other direction.

Comment: Thank u very much for the clarification . But i don't know that i m asking true or false question but .. acceleration=velocity/time , so velocity and acceleration are directly proportional to each other right ? so the examples that i and you have mentioned is against it.

Comment: $\Delta v / \Delta t$ is different of $v/t$

Comment: @Angeline varghese  *acceleration=velocity/time* is wrong. It is change in velocity per unit time.

Comment: Okay got it .. But according to maths , a=dv/dt .. so when v is zero,as zero is contant, derivative of it will be zero , so acceleration should be zero right?

Comment: @Angelinevarghese No, that’s not how derivatives work. Think about the derivative of $2t$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @G.Smith , sorry actually i didn't understand ,can u pls explain in a better way ?

Comment: Do you know what the derivative of $2t$ with respect to $t$ is? Or have you not learned about calculus yet?

Comment: the answer is 2 right ?

Comment: Yes, everywhere, including where $t$ is zero. If a function is zero at one point, it does *not* mean that its derivative is zero there. So your comment starting with “Okay...” was wrong. A zero velocity *at one instant* does not imply zero acceleration.

Comment: @Angeline varghese before thinking of change in velocity you must think of how that change has come I.e. what brought that change and hence we look out for **force**. If force acts all the time velocity will change at every Instant.

Comment: Is it correct to say that acceleration at the top most is because of the force exerted due to gravity not because of the force we had thrown the ball vertically up : so acceleration due to the force that we gave to throw it upward is zero, but the acceleartion it have is due to gravity?

Comment: What i meant to say was that there are two forces acting ; one is what we gave in upwrad drection and the other one is in the opp. direction which is due to gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is defined as the change in velocity per unit time. And this change can occur only if there exists a **Force** . Also If the change is positive i.e. final velocity is greater than initial velocity then this means that the acceleration is positive i.e. the force which is causing the acceleration is in the same direction of velocity.

But when a ball is thrown upward the gravitational force acting on the ball pulls it down to the earth and that's why it's velocity keeps on decreasing and at a certain height it becomes zero but still at that height gravitational force is pulling the body . So acceleration is still there. And after that ball starts to speed up since force is acting in the same direction of its  velocity.

So it's better to define **acceleration with respect to force**. *If force acts then we notice a change in velocity i.e. acceleration and if the force is removed then there will be no acceleration.*

Also according to Newton's second law of motion

**Acceleration is proportional to the net force acting on the body**.

Answer (score 0):

the right formulation would be: change of velocity  in short time is  proportional to acceleration.
You can drive with constant high velocity and no acceleration.
$$ a*\Delta t= v_e-v_b$$
at the top your ball has the velocity v_b=0  the acceleration is 10m/s^2 that says, that after 0,1s the velocity will be 1m/s

Answer (score 0):

> Velocity and acceleration are directly proportional to each other,

No, Velocity and acceleration are not directly proportional to each other. The direct proportionalities are:

- The velocity is directly proportional to the distance travelled or the magnitude of the displacement, in the same direction as the displacement.
- The acceleration is directly proportional to the magnitude of the force, in the same direction as the force.
- Change in velocity is directly proportional to time when acceleration is constant.

> ... in the case of throwing a ball up , at the top velocity is zero but acceleration is there.

See this question: [Why isn't the acceleration at the top point of a ball’s journey zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210329/why-isnt-the-acceleration-at-the-top-point-of-a-ball-s-journey-zero)